# waiting until URLSession.shared.dataTask ends

Tags: swiftui

I have the below code. I got **print "OK Call"** before to **print (finalData)**. I know the reason is URLSession goes in parallel, but my question is: How could avoid the parallel task and wait until URLSession ends ? THANKS

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
    Button ("Action", action: {
                    self.checkLogin(username:"test", password:"123456")
                    print ("OK Call")
                } ) }

func checkLogin (username: String, password: String) {  

    var body: [String:String] = [:]
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://test/apple/login.php") else { return  }
    body = ["user": username, "password": password]
    let finalBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode (body)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = finalBody
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
        if let error = error { print ("Error: \(error)")
                               return
           }
        if let data = data { 
            let finalData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ServerMessage.self, from: data)
            print (finalData)
            return
           }
    }.resume()
}
}

struct ServerMessage: Decodable {
    let result: String
    let nuser: String
}
```

Comment: Don't wait. Move the `print("OK Call")` line or the things you want to do into the completion handler of the data task.

Comment: that is my question, what is the alternative to the async process.? So, the URLSession ends before the app continues.

Comment: It does not end, the data task is alive until the asynchronous completion handler is executed later in time. Therefore do things like updating the UI inside the completion handler.